# how is it called when people reject foreign solutions?

Tags: software-design

How is it called when people refuse to accept third party solutions? For example you need a certain framework but instead of using a well established and tested one you start building your own (in-house) framework.

I once read an wiki article about this psychosocial behaviour, but forget the specific term of it and don't know how to google it.

Comment: It's NIH syndrome (Not Invented Here). Even though I'm not supposed to say that because this question is totally not appropriate for SO. I'm going to beat myself up later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NIH syndrome (Not Invented Here) as Jeroen Mostert pointed out. Thanks.